# Using EventHandler of Library in Javascript and "this" modifier

Tags: javascript, class, object, this, eventhandler

Just an Example here, Using websocket in browser.
Same happened when using Nodejs with ws Library for Websocket.

If you write everything out side a class, all the handlers will be called:
EG:

```
try {
    var host = "ws://localhost:8080";
    var socket = new WebSocket(host); 

    socket.onopen = function(){ 
         // Do something
    } 
    socket.onmessage = function(msg){ // all stuff here will be called upon receiving message
         // Do something
    } 
    socket.onclose = function(){ 
         // Do something
    }            
} catch(exception){ 
     // Do something
}
```

How ever, if you want to instantiate in a class, non of the handlers will be called

```
var ws = new webSocketModule();

var webSocketModule = function(){
    try {
        var host = "ws://localhost:8080";
        this.socket = new WebSocket(host); 

        this.socket.onopen = function(){ 
             // Do something
        } 
        this.socket.onmessage = function(msg){ // None of these are called upon receiving message, however the server side will have connection message that means the websocket object is functioning just fine.
             // Do something
        } 
        this.socket.onclose = function(){ 
             // Do something
        }            
    } catch(exception){ 
         // Do something
    } 
}
```

So is it that I have to do it the messy way of putting everything globally?

To Add to the question

```
var ws = new webSocketModule();

var webSocketModule = function(){
    try {
        var host = "ws://localhost:8080";
        this.socket = new WebSocket(host); 

        this.socket.onopen = function(){ 
             // Do something
        } 
        this.socket.onmessage = function(msg){
             // Do something
        } 
        this.socket.onclose = function(){ 
             // Do something
        }            
    } catch(exception){ 
         // Do something
    } 
}

ws.socket.onmessage = function(msg){
    // This will be called, kinda confusing
}
```

=================================================================
Added:

```
var ws = new webSocketModule();  //Explain: This is the instance in the main file

// Down below is in eg: webSocketModule.js
var webSocketModule = function(){
    try {
        var host = "ws://localhost:8080";
        var skt = this.socket = new WebSocket(host); 

        skt.onopen = function(){ 
             // Do something
        } 
        skt.onmessage = function(msg){
             // Using a local variable for socket will not make this respond
             // Another side will successfully show connected and send the message
             // (At least it successfully printed the console log after the socket.send)
             // You have to register it like the above block "ws.socket.onmessage = ..." in the main file to make it respond
             // But this and the object should be the same point of reference right?
             // Seems Javascript handles it differently than JAVA or C++, is there any book that recommended that talks about how browser or NodeJS handles it? thanks.
             // Do something
        } 
        skt.onclose = function(){ 
             // Do something
        }            
    } catch(exception){ 
         // Do something
    } 
}
```

Comment: make them all like the first one by using var socket = this.socket = new WebSocket(host); that way you avoid the repetition, and you still have all the socket properties just a dot away.

Comment: You need to assign `webSocketModule` before you do `var ws = new webSocketModule()`.

Comment: do you get any errors? if not, try putting a `console.log('test')` inside the `webSocketModule`. does it get hit?

Comment: No error, console didn't log, that was how I knew it didn't respond. THanks :)

Comment: var ws = new webSocketModule();
    
    var webSocketModule = function(){
        try {
            var host = "ws://localhost:8080";
            var skt = this.socket = new WebSocket(host); 
    
            skt.onopen = function(){ 
                 // Do something
            } 
            skt.onmessage = function(msg){
                 // Do something
            } 
            skt.onclose = function(){ 
                 // Do something
            }            
        } catch(exception){ 
             // Do something
        } 
    }

Socket still works,but handlers were not called

Answer (score 0):

are you instantiating your webSocketModule?

```
var webSocketModule = function() { ... }

var instance = new webSocketModule();
```

because you assigned `webSocketModule` to a variable, it must beassigned before it can be used. If you used a [named function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) then it wouldn't matter

Comment: I had "var ws = new webSocketModule();"

ws was the instance and the connection is performed correctly.
It's only that all the event Handlers that registered using "this" in the constructor didn't respond.

Thanks